# Rewrite rule not working, but only when parameter is text

Tags: php, permalinks, urls, htaccess, slug

I have a simple rewrite rule that changes something like /locations/?slug=times-square to /locations/times-square/. The same "location" can be retrieved by ID, so the following URL's all work and retrieve the same data:

```
/locations/?slug=times-square
/locations/?slug=108366
/locations/108366
```

The last one shows that my rewrite rule works fine when the slug is a number. The rule is as follows:

```
RewriteRule   ^locations/(.+)$   locations/?slug=$1   [L]
```

But writing a URL as follows: `/locations/times-square` gives me a 404 error, and that's obviously the one I prefer. Is wordpress redirecting this as an error before it even makes it to the rewrite rule? How can I stop this?

Comment: Where exactly are you putting this directive in relation to the existing directives in your `.htaccess` file? To confirm, is this URL is ultimately handled by WordPress? As far as the `RewriteRule` is concerned, there is no difference here between numbers and letters - so the problem is _something else_. Note, however, that this `RewriteRule` executes long before it ever gets to WordPress (depending on where you've put this in your `.htaccess` file).

Comment: I put it right at the beginning of the htaccess file and it didn't seem to help. The htaccess file is in the root public directory of the website–same place Wordpress is installed. This page (/locations/) is a Wordpress page, but with a custom template, which takes the parameter from ?slug= to display mostly custom information from the database.

Comment: "I put it right at the beginning of the htaccess file and it didn't seem to help." - Well, it certainly needs to go before the WordPress front-controller or it won't do anything. "Is wordpress redirecting this as an error before it even makes it to the rewrite rule?" - WordPress is probably seeing this as a 404 _after_ the URL has been rewritten (because WP uses the original REQUEST_URI to route the URL - this isn't changed by the Apache rewrite) - however, I don't see why there would be a difference between numbers and letters? (The URL with a number/ID should also fail??!)